# How to animate a custom shape object in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, shapes

I am relatively new to c# and WPF, maybe that’s why I cannot find the (probably very obvious) answer to my problem. I have been trying and googling but with no success.

I have a custom shape class that returns 3 RectangleGeometries in a GeometryGroup. The 3 corresponding rectangles can be displayed in a Canvas in MainWindow as expected. I would now like to animate each of the rectangles individually, say drop the first one to the bottom of the canvas, rotate the second one and animate the width of the third one.

My own research says the key are Dependency Properties. So I registered them but I couldn’t get them to do any changes on the rectangles.

Preferably, I would do all this in code behind. Only the Canvas 
has been added in XAML. Can it be done? Here is some code to work with.

Thank you in advance

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        CustomShape customShape = new CustomShape();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            customShape.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            cnvMain.Children.Add(customShape);
        }
    }

    class CustomShape : Shape
    {
        private Rect rect1, rect2, rect3;
        private RectangleGeometry rg1, rg2, rg3;
        private GeometryGroup allRectangleGeometries = new GeometryGroup();

        //Constructor
        public CustomShape()
        {
            makeCustomShape();
        }

        private void makeCustomShape()
        {
            rect1 = new Rect(50, 20, 100, 50);
            rg1 = new RectangleGeometry(rect1);
            allRectangleGeometries.Children.Add(rg1);

            rect2 = new Rect(200, 20, 60, 20);
            rg2 = new RectangleGeometry(rect2);
            allRectangleGeometries.Children.Add(rg2);

            rect3 = new Rect(300, 20, 200, 80);
            rg3 = new RectangleGeometry(rect3);
            allRectangleGeometries.Children.Add(rg3);
        }

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get
            {
                return allRectangleGeometries;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found an answer myself.
I implemented 3 Dependency Properties and a Callback method that is executed every time a property changes.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        CustomShape customShape = new CustomShape();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            customShape.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            cnvMain.Children.Add(customShape);
        }

        private void ButtonAnimate_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation rec1Animation = new DoubleAnimation(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            customShape.BeginAnimation(CustomShape.Rec1YProperty, rec1Animation);

            DoubleAnimation rec2Animation = new DoubleAnimation(360, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            customShape.BeginAnimation(CustomShape.Rec2RotateProperty, rec2Animation);

            DoubleAnimation rec3Animation = new DoubleAnimation(400, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            customShape.BeginAnimation(CustomShape.Rec3WidthProperty, rec3Animation);
        }
    }

    class CustomShape : Shape
    {
        private Rect rect1, rect2, rect3;
        private RectangleGeometry rg1, rg2, rg3;
        private GeometryGroup allRectangleGeometries = new GeometryGroup();

        public double Rec1Y
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(Rec1YProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Rec1YProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Rec1YProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rec1Y", typeof(double), typeof(CustomShape), new PropertyMetadata(20d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAnyPropertyChanged)));

        public double Rec2Rotate
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(Rec2RotateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Rec2RotateProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Rec2RotateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rec2Rotate", typeof(double), typeof(CustomShape), new PropertyMetadata(0d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAnyPropertyChanged)));

        public double Rec3Width
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(Rec3WidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Rec3WidthProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Rec3WidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rec3Width", typeof(double), typeof(CustomShape), new PropertyMetadata(200d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAnyPropertyChanged)));

        //Constructor
        public CustomShape()
        {
            makeCustomShape();
        }

        private void makeCustomShape()
        {
            rect1 = new Rect(50, Rec1Y, 100, 50);
            rg1 = new RectangleGeometry(rect1);
            allRectangleGeometries.Children.Add(rg1);

            rect2 = new Rect(200, 20, 60, 20);
            rg2 = new RectangleGeometry(rect2);
            rg2.Transform = new RotateTransform(Rec2Rotate, 230, 30);
            allRectangleGeometries.Children.Add(rg2);

            rect3 = new Rect(300, 20, Rec3Width, 80);
            rg3 = new RectangleGeometry(rect3);
            allRectangleGeometries.Children.Add(rg3);
        }

        private static void OnAnyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {           
            CustomShape customShape = source as CustomShape;
            customShape.allRectangleGeometries.Children.Clear();
            customShape.makeCustomShape();
        }

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get
            {
                return allRectangleGeometries;
            }
        }
    }
}
```